# libGDX circle won't restart after collision

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I follow this tutorial http://www.kilobolt.com/day-10-gamestates-and-high-score.html to make my game restart, but have a problem with my bird object that I would be thankful I anyone could help me to solve.
The problem is when ever the bird hit a pipe or the ground, it's circle that check the collision remain at the spot the bird died at when a new game beings and the bird animation move regularly but without the circle to check for collision.
In the bird object I already created the circle and I'm calling it in the render method the following way (inside an if statement):
    (Intersector.overlaps(pipe, bird.getBoundingCircle()))
The pipe is a Rectangle that receives the pipe's texture in the render class, and in contrast to the bird's circle it restart correctly every new game.

Comment: Other then saying, remove or reassign the circle to the new player object we need more code to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if that is supposed to be like that, you have not completed the whole tutorial, so maybe that is fixed in next lessons. Try to download the source code that is provided at the end of the article and compare with your code.

I also followed that tutorial and despite some minor tweaks that I had to put in place, I managed to have a working clone of flappy bird.

Comment: I currently finished day 10 with my own changes to try and understand and improve my coding. The problem, I believe, is that I think that I missed where in the tutorial the code tells the bird's BoundingCircle to restart with the bird's texture...

Comment: OK. Followed your advice and found what I missed. Thanks!